# ¿Cómo programar en Python Tkinter un botón para desplegar una captura de calendario y luego otro botón para cerrar?

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.9

He escrito un código que funciona en línea de comandos y lo quiero hacer más amigable para usuario y se ejecute desde una GUI. La cosa es que hay que seleccionar rangos de fechas, entonces he creado un menú que con un botón abre y despliega un calendario, luego se selecciona un rango de fechas y se despliega para verificar, luego con un botón cerrar lo cierra y vuelve al menú original. Todo bien hasta ahí, pero si quiero volver a ejecutar el calendario sale un error. He buscado otras alternativas sin éxito.

Dejo el código de cómo es la forma que más avances tiene.

```
   import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from calendario_v13 import CapturadorRangoVentana

class InterfazMenu:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.master.title("Interfaz Menú")

        self.menu_frame = ttk.Frame(master, padding="10")
        self.menu_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)

        self.boton_calendario = ttk.Button(self.menu_frame, text="Abrir Calendario", command=self.abrir_calendario)
        self.boton_calendario.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)

        self.contenido_frame = ttk.Frame(master, padding="10")
        self.contenido_frame.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)

        self.resultado_var = tk.StringVar()
        self.resultado_label = ttk.Label(self.contenido_frame, textvariable=self.resultado_var)
        self.resultado_label.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2, pady=10)

    def abrir_calendario(self):
        capturador_rango = CapturadorRangoVentana(self.contenido_frame, self.mostrar_resultado)
        capturador_rango.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=2, padx=10, pady=10)

    def mostrar_resultado(self, mensaje):
        self.resultado_var.set(mensaje)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = InterfazMenu(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

La otra parte dónde en calendario_v13.py:

```py
...
self.boton_cerrar = ttk.Button(self, text="Cerrar", command=self.cerrar)
self.boton_cerrar.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=2, pady=10)
...
def cerrar(self):
    self.master.destroy()
```

Les dejo unas capturas de imagen y error:
[image: menu]
[image: selección rango]
[image: cierre]

Luego si vuelvo a ejecutar el abrir:

> Exception in Tkinter callback
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\mrxcub\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter_*init*_.py", line 1885, in **call**
> return self.func(*args)
> File "D:\2024\python_2024\Nueva carpeta (2)\menu_v14.py", line 26, in abrir_calendario
> capturador_rango = CapturadorRangoVentana(self.contenido_frame, self.mostrar_resultado)
> File "D:\2024\python_2024\Nueva carpeta (2)\calendario_v13.py", line 8, in **init**
> super().**init**(master)
> File "C:\Users\mrxcub\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter_*init*_.py", line 3121, in **init**
> Widget.**init**(self, master, 'frame', cnf, {}, extra)
> File "C:\Users\mrxcub\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter_*init*_.py", line 2569, in **init**
> self.tk.call(
> _tkinter.TclError: bad window path name ".!frame2"

La idea es un menú principal por ejemplo con 3 procesos (botones)
Boton 1 (proceso 1): Consulta frutas. Hace clic y en este proceso debe buscar frutas en un rango de fechas, entonces debe capturar fechas (y puede hacerlo varias veces porque luego los rangos que se ocupan para esta consulta se hacen en este u otros procesos). De hecho lo que quiero hacer es que un un usuario escoja un proceso y luego se despliegue la selección del rango de fechas y luego hacer otras consultas al usuario, se pone botón ejecuta y responde con el resultado; después que termine y vuelva al menú principal para escoger hacer otro proceso 2 (verduras) o 3 (Carnes) y se desplieguen las fechas, y después poder volver al proceso 1 si quiere, etc.

Comment: No hay problema, sin embargo, no se me ocurre como ayudarte, ya que no puedo reproducir el error y la parte con dicho error no está publicada. No digo que publiques todo, solo un [ejemplo minimo, completo y verificable](/help/minimal-reproducible-example). De paso, para conocer mejor el sitio (no es un foro), te invito a leer más del centro de ayuda :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que **estas destruyendo el frame contenedor de tus widgets `CapturadorRangoVentana`** (frame al que hace referencia el atributo `contenido_frame`).

Dicho frame es creado en el inicializador de la clase `InterfazMenu` y es usado como padre de `CapturadorRangoVentana` posteriormente:

```
capturador_rango = CapturadorRangoVentana(self.contenido_frame, ...)
```

El problema es que luego en tu clase `CapturadorRangoVentana` en el método `cerrar` haces:

```
self.master.destroy()
```

esto destruye la instancia del `Frame` al que hace referencia `contenido_frame` en el lado de TCL/Tk. Cuando luego vuelves a pulsar el botón <kbd>Abrir Calendario</kbd>, al intentar inicializar `CapturadorRangoVentana` de nuevo se encuentra con que el widget padre no existe y de ahí el error de TCL:

```
bad window path name ".!frame2"
```

`!Frame2` es el nombre de ese widget `ttk.Frame` (generado automáticamente, ya que no especificas uno mediante el argumento `name`) y que es usado por TCL/Tk para identificar el widget. Aunque tkinter usa referencias, internamente TCL usa *pathnames* para referirse a los widgets.

La solución mas simple es que no destruyas el `Frame` padre, destruye solo el widget, la instancia de `CapturadorRangoVentana`:

```
def cerrar(self)
    self.destroy()
```

o si solo haces eso en el método `cerrar`, entonces puedes ahorrarte el *wrapper*, simplemente:

```
self.boton_cerrar = ttk.Button(
    self,
    text="Cerrar",
    command=self.destroy
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hola @FJSevilla y a la comunidad.

Muchas gracias por tus comentarios e inmensa ayuda. Comentar que he probado las dos alternativas y funciona bien. Una cosa que me falta probar es si la lista que he creado con el rengo de fecha, logro llamar desde el menu principal antes que se elimine la ventana. Pondré *una parte del código* por si a alguien le pueda ser útil. Además, creo que mi diseño de GUI, no es la apropiada. ¿Podrían por favor sugerirme algún link para aprender? No sé los conceptos básicos, y no estoy seguro de si mi código está estructurado correctamente y si sigue las convenciones de programación. Por ejemplo tal vez sea mejor usar "Toplevel" (no sé como sería) o bien como se debe hacer la herencia correcta...
Por otro lado, me puedes explicar "ya que no especificas uno mediante el argumento name) ", dónde va eso, me refiero dónde debería ponerle nombre?

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkcalendar import DateEntry
from datetime import datetime
class CapturadorRangoVentana(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, callback_mostrar_resultado):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.callback_mostrar_resultado = callback_mostrar_resultado



        ttk.Label(self, text="Fecha de Inicio:").grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)
        self.date_entry_inicio = DateEntry(self, width=12, background='darkblue', foreground='white', borderwidth=2)
        self.date_entry_inicio.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)
        self.date_entry_inicio.bind("<<DateEntrySelected>>", self.validate_date)

        ttk.Label(self, text="Fecha de Fin:").grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)
        self.date_entry_fin = DateEntry(self, width=12, background='darkblue', foreground='white', borderwidth=2)
        self.date_entry_fin.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)
        self.date_entry_fin.set_date(self.today)
        self.date_entry_fin.bind("<<DateEntrySelected>>", self.validate_date)

        self.boton_capturar = ttk.Button(self, text="Capturar Rango", command=self.capturar_rango)
        self.boton_capturar.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=2, pady=10)

        self.boton_cerrar = ttk.Button(self, text="Cerrar", command=self.destroy)
        self.boton_cerrar.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=2, pady=10)

        self.resultado_frame = tk.Frame(self)
        self.resultado_frame.grid(row=4, column=0, columnspan=2, pady=10)

        self.resultado_text = tk.Text(self.resultado_frame, height=13, state="disabled")
        self.resultado_text.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky="nsew")

        scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(self.resultado_frame, command=self.resultado_text.yview)
        scrollbar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="ns")
        self.resultado_text.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
```

Muchas gracias por tu gentileza y amabilidad de compartir tú conocimiento. Mi área de trabajo no es esta (informatica) pero en lo que hago comparto todo lo que puedo.

Muchas gracias y saludos

Comment: Esta es la sección de _respuestas_. Si tienes aún dudas, y están relacionadas a tu pregunta, debes editar tu pregunta en cuestión. Por cierto, las menciones (@) no funcionan en las respuestas, y si quieres preguntar algo específico al usuario que mencionaste, comenta su respuesta. [Evita los saludos](/help/behavior), y si en realidad es una nueva pregunta, [formula una nueva](/questions/ask).